# How to implement OAauth2 private_key_jwt authorization using new spring-authorization-server (JWS, JWT Bearer)

Tags: spring-security

Do you have any samples how to implement `private_key_jwt` authentication using [new spring authorization server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server)?

It is supported, which you can find in [project wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/wiki/Feature-List), but there is no documentation how to to it.

The only samples that I found (and it worked) were Authorization Code with PKCE: [The New Spring Authorization Server with Kotlin](https://medium.com/codex/the-new-spring-authorization-server-with-kotlin-20ccf47f2274) and [Spring Authorization Server Tutorial](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/spring-authorization-server-tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

Our [official samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples) are in the main repository.

Unfortunately, we don't have a sample for that yet and I don't have anything handy. You can request one by opening an issue, or ask for a how-to guide like those found linked to [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/499).

Comment: Thanks Steve, I've created an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/747#issue-1243204260