# How to implement a custom OAauth2 authorization with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Looking at the new spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server library, I need to implement a custom authorization server for a resource server. Actually, I intend to manually implement the PRIVATE_KEY_JWT Authentication method that is either [not yet implemented](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/747) or [lacking examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72305586/how-to-implement-oaauth2-private-key-jwt-authorization-using-new-spring-authoriz). I followed [one good example](https://www.codeburps.com/post/spring-boot-oauth2-for-server-to-server-security) that uses this approach (the authorization server issuing the access token to the resource server). The resource server has a simple configuration that points to my issuer (authorization server) as in the code:

```
spring:
 security:
   oauth2:
     resourceserver:
       jwt:
         issuer-uri: http://auth-server:9000
```

but this approach uses client-id and client-secret credentials like:

```
 @Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
}

@Bean
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .clientId("client_id123")
            .clientSecret("{noop}secret123")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .scope("https://purl.imsglobal.org/spec/lti-ags/scope/score")
            .build();

    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
}
```

I appreciate if anyone could refer me an example of either a PRIVATE_KEY_JWT implementation or a custom authorization implementation that receives a JWT and issues an access token.

Answer (score 0):

In application.yml set up the location of the certs, and create a config class RsaKeyProperties to load them:

```
rsa:
  privateKey: classpath:certs/private.pem
  publicKey: classpath:certs/public.pem
```

Then in WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
  @Bean
  protected SecurityFilterChain configure(
      BasicAuthFilter basicAuthFilter,
      ActivitiAuthenticationFilter activitiAuthenticationFilter,
      HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        // Disabling CSRF is safe for token-based API's
        .csrf().disable()
        .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
          auth.antMatchers(
               "/api/authenticate/**",
               "/api/tenants/**").permitAll();
          auth.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();

          // When an exception is thrown, ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration sets stuff up so that /error is called
          // internally using an anonymous user. Without this line, the call to /error fails with a 403 error
          // because anonymous users would not be able to view the page.
          auth.antMatchers("/error").anonymous();
        })
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(RsaKeyProperties rsaKeyProperties) {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKeyProperties.publicKey()).build();
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder(RsaKeyProperties rsaKeyProperties) {
    JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaKeyProperties.publicKey())
        .privateKey(rsaKeyProperties.privateKey())
        .build();
    JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
    return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
  }
}
```

The "SCOPE_" prefix that the identity server library was adding in the JWT didn't work well with spring security as far as I could figure out, so I removed that:

```
  /**
   * For some reason the JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter defaults to adding the prefix "SCOPE_" to all
   * the claims in the token, so we need to provide a JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter that doesn't do
   * that and just passes them through.
   */
  @Bean
  public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("");

    JwtAuthenticationConverter authConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    authConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return authConverter;
  }
```

Comment: do you have a git repo link for this example ? I am unsure where to put each configuration and also missing some libs...